# Entity Framework Update nested list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use Entity Framework 6 (Code First). I have a class:

```
public class DialogSession {...}
```

And another class with a list of `DialogSession` objects:

```
public class DialogUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<DialogSession> DialogSessions { get; set; }
}
```

I add `DialogSession` object to the list and then execute `context.SaveChanges()` as follows:

```
dialogUser.DialogSessions.Add(dialogSession);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But the foreign key of the `dialogSession` record still Null:

[image]

I've tried using many methods on the web like the follows but withoyt success:

```
context.DialogUsers.Attach(dialogUser);
context.Entry(dialogUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChangesExtention();
```

Does anyone know how to save inner objects (like the list) in the database using Entity Framework (6)?

Comment: Above code did not demonstrate relationship between `DialogSession ` and `DialogUser.Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question is not clear which relationship type do you have, so I guess you have One-to-Many and something like this should works:

```
public class DialogSession
{
    public int DialogSessionId { get; set; }
    public virtual DialogUser DialogUser { get; set; }
}

public class DialogUser
{
    public int DialogUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DialogSession> DialogSessions { get; set; }
}
```

Take a look at example how properly configure this type of relationship in this [article](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you should add

```
dialogUser.DialogSessions.Add(dialogSession);
context.Entry(dialogUser).State = EntityState.Modified; 
context.SaveChanges();
```

This will mark the entity as modified and then the changes should be reflected on the db.

This could be done a more efficiently by marking singular properties as modified

```
dialogUser.DialogSessions.Add(dialogSession);
context.Entry(dialogUser).Property(u => u.dialogSession).IsModified = true; 
context.SaveChanges();
```

Give it a try :)

Comment: Yup, because of what @ja

Comment: Cant edit my comment -.-
But yeah, because of what @Jacob explained in his answer

Answer (score 0):

Please see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx

You should use a virtual list for the child entity, and ensure that the DialogSessions class also refers back to its parent with a DialogUserId property (so named by convention)

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class DialogSession
{
    [Key]
    public int DialogSessionId { get; set; }
    public int DialogUser { get; set; }
}

public class DialogUser
{
    [Key]
    public int DialogUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DialogSession> DialogSessions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).